# Unique dropdown item is not adding to the form

Tags: angular

I'm having an angular form with a button. When user clicks the button , I need to show a dropdown control with a label. (Values of dropdown is already defined) When user clicks the button next time, a new dropdown control should be added to the form (but the values of the dropdown is same as the previous one). I have tried something. But when user select a value from dropdown and when user add the dropdown for the second time that selected value also disappear. Please help to fix the issue.

```
<form #monthForm="ngForm">
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Duration</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of duration let i=index">
            <td>{{item.label}}</td>
            <td>
                <select [(ngModel)]="item[i]" name="something">
                    <option *ngFor="let a of item.status">{{a.name}}</option>
                </select>      
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  (click)="addDuration()">Add Duration</button>

</form>
```

Controller

```
options = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Test' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Test2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Test3' },

    { id: 4, name: 'Test4' },
  ]



  addDuration() {


    this.duration.push({
      label: "test",
      status: this.options,
    })

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use FormArray to dynamically add field to the form. First you should create a formArray in the OnInit lifecyclehook and assign it to myForm.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      arr: this.fb.array([this.createItem()])
    })
  }
```

Then create the this dropdown field name by the following:

```
createItem() {
    return this.fb.group({
      status: [''],
    })
  }
```

Then create method for add and attach to formGroup

```
addItem() {
    this.arr = this.myForm.get('arr') as FormArray;
    this.arr.push(this.createItem());
  }
```

Lastly Submit() method when you are done and submit the form

```
onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.myForm.value);
}
```

In component.html:

```
<tr formArrayName="arr" *ngFor="let a of myForm.get('arr').controls; let i = index">
  <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
    <td>test</td>
    <td>
      <select name="something" formControlName="status">
        <option *ngFor="let a of options">{{a.name}}</option>
      </select>      
    </td>
  </ng-container>
</tr>
```

Here we want to add the `<tr>` recursively when adding new dropdown to the form. So we add the formArray here and the  is used to hold the entire row using formGroupName. Then we implement formControlName for status and loop through options for selecting the options.

## Live Example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-form-under-table-solve)